# Routing InfoPath Forms

Tags: workflow, infopath

I'm looking at automating some forms for my organization utilizing SharePoint and InfoPath. I'm familiar with form development and saving them to SharePoint. Where we start getting stuck is managing permissions on the library that houses the documents.

For example.

- Employee submits a form for approval to supervisor (only supervisor, employee, and admin assistant should see the form).
- Once the form is approved, it should be seen by the supervisor, employee, admin assistant and HR department.

  - Employee should only see their own forms
  - Supervisor and admin assistant should only see their departments forms
  - HR should see everything.

Any thoughts on how to best accomplish this?